# How can I place a caption for the more subfigures?

Tags: captions, includegraphics

I want to a caption for the three figures but I want to be like a title. My code is:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image2.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image3.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image4.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: You mention "a caption for the three figures" but the screenshot and the code you included clearly has 4 images. Do you want to center the "title"  with respect to all 4 images or just with respect to three of the images? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{A caption for all images at once}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \textbf{\Large Something like a title}
  \medskip
  
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```